# Output multiple plots into single file in R within a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, output, bar-chart

I have the following datamatrix:

```
TranscriptID    GeneID  Biotype TranscriptName  CommonNAme  GeneName    TSS-ID  Locus-ID    DNp63D-DMECs-1  DNp63D-DMECs-2  DNp63D-DMECs-3  DNp63WTMECs-1   DNp63WTMECs-2   Fold    2-tailedtest
Test1   TestA   protein_coding  Fun1    Ex1 Ex1 ExA1    ExA1    1.15E-08    2.68E-12    0.005077929 4.99E-07    6.38E-08    6.02E+03    0.495089687
Test2   TestB   protein_coding  Fun2    Ex2 Ex2 ExA2    ExA2    3.69E-08    0.014129129 0.075213367 0.121370367 0.404553833 1.13E-01    0.123434776
Test3   TestC   protein_coding  Fun3    Ex3 Ex3 ExA3    ExA3    4.89E-05    0   0   6.58E-05    1.64E-34    4.96E-01    0.643007583
Test4   TestA   protein_coding  Fun4    Ex4 Ex4 ExA4    ExA4    0.058629449 0   0   0.056200966 0.253314667 1.26E-01    0.180082201
Test5   TestB   protein_coding  Fun5    Ex5 Ex5 ExA5    ExA5    7.80E-06    0   0   1.42E-11    4.20E-36    3.66E+05    0.495026427
Test6   TestC   protein_coding  Fun6    Ex6 Ex6 ExA6    ExA6    0   0   0   0   2.41E-101   0.00E+00    0.272228401
Test7   TestA   protein_coding  Fun7    Ex7 Ex7 ExA7    ExA7    3.77E-08    0.023945749 0.077103517 0.262936167 0.2940195   1.21E-01    0.004479038
Test8   TestB   protein_coding  Fun8    Ex8 Ex8 ExA8    ExA8    9.30E-09    4.82E-14    0.000827853 8.19E-07    7.47E-07    3.52E+02    0.496141526
```

I would like to generate a barplot for mean and standard error of the mean for each of the rows where columns 9 to 11 represent group A, and columns 12 to 13 represent group B. I wrote the following R script that works without a problem but I was wondering if :

1. there is any advice to optimize this script to make it run faster specially when i will have hundreds of rows sometimes and more columns.

   2. Is there a way to ensure that each 8 plots are output into a single file? Hence, my output would look like a matrix of 8 barplots
      I tried multiplot function using:

   multiplot(q, cols=4) #assuming this will draw 4 columns and each column will have 2 plots towards the end of my script below but that did not work. The current script below outputs each plot in a different file

My R code:

```
input <- read.delim(file="MECs-DNp63IsoformLevels.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
input<-as.matrix(input)



for (i in 1:nrow(input)) {
mean1 <- mean(as.numeric(input[i,12:13]))
mean2 <- mean(as.numeric(input[i,9:11]))
sd1 <- sd(as.numeric(input[i,12:13]))
sd2 <- sd(as.numeric(input[i,9:11]))
sem1 <- sd2/sqrt(length(input[i,12:13]))
sem2 <- sd1/sqrt(length(input[i,9:11]))

mean_sem <- data.frame(mean=c(mean1, mean2), sem=c(sem1, sem2), group=c("WT", "DNp63D-D")) 
mean_sem$group<-factor(mean_sem$group, levels=mean_sem$group, ordered=TRUE) #this prevents ggplot from ordering the x-axis alphabaetically and keeps the order as the input dataframe
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 20))
print(i)
p<- ggplot(mean_sem, aes(x=group, y=mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=.3, colour="black", fill=c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem),
                width=.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=group)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) + 
  xlab('Genotype of MECs') +
  ylab('Quantile Norm FPKM')

q = p +ggtitle(input[i,5])

ggsave(filename=paste(input[i,5],'.png', sep=""), plot=q)

}
```

An example of the output is:
[image]

As i indicated, the above script works. but can i optimize it to run faster on larger data sets? Also, how can I output 8 images into one file in a for loop.

My goal is to have an output similar to the below (it can be 2 columns and 4 rows, or any combination.. as long as within the for loop i could output multiple graphs to one plot).

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know there was something dedicated just to that. I will make sure exist time to post things in Code Review

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I have expanded/edited the question to make it more relevant

Comment: It sounds like your data are spread out across columns?  While I'm a fan of melting data (`reshape2::melt`), this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35142223/4718512) uses `apply` to work across sets of columns (like your data?), create plots, and combine them (using grobs).

Comment: @oshun i never wrote a function in R. I did try it though and I posted my result [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118723/convert-a-for-loop-in-r-to-apply-function) . I am not sure if that's what you meant. yet, i cant get 8 figures/file.