# How to automate linear regression of multiple rows in a loop and plot using R

Tags: r, function, loops

I am working with 2 data frames and trying to automate the way I currently do.

```
ID <- c("ID101","ID102","ID103","ID104","ID105","ID106","ID107","ID108","ID109","ID110")
A <- c(420,440,490,413,446,466,454,433,401,414)
B <- c(230,240,295,253,266,286,254,233,201,214)
C <- c(20,40,90,13,46,66,54,33,61,14)
D <- c(120,140,190,113,146,166,154,133,101,114)
E <- c(38,34,33,56,87,31,12,44,68,91)
F <- c(938,934,973,956,987,931,962,944,918,921)
df1 <- data.frame(ID,A,B,C,D,E,F)

Upstream <- c("A","C","E")
Downstream <- c("B","D","F")
df2 <- data.frame(Upstream,Downstream)
```

I am currently running a simple linear regression between upstream and downstream data and plot its residuals along with it. The way I do it manually is

```
fit <- lm(A ~ B, data=df)

lm_eqn <- function(df){
  m <- lm(A ~ B, df);
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(R)^2~"="~r2* "," ~~ RMSE ~"="~rmse, 
                   list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3),
                        rmse = round(sqrt(mean(resid(m)^2,na.rm=TRUE)), 3)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));
}

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(colour="red",size = 3) + geom_smooth(method=lm) + geom_text(aes(size=10),x = -Inf, hjust = -1, y = Inf, vjust = 1, label = lm_eqn(df), parse = TRUE,show.legend = F)
p2 <-  ggplot(df, aes(x=B, y=resid(fit))) + ylab("Residuals") + geom_point(shape=1,colour="red",size = 3) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2,top=textGrob("Regression data", 
                                         gp=gpar(cex=1.5, fontface="bold")))
```

I get this plot

[image]

I redo this manually for the next row in df2 which is C & D and then manually change the parameters again for the next row which is E & F.

How can I use functions or automate this logic so that I run only one time and get the 3 plots, one for each (A&B), (C&D), (E&F).

Please let me know if I am not clear on what I want. Ideally I am looking a way to code up so that I don't manually need to enter the values (A,B,C,D,E,F) at the respective places every time I run. Kindly please provide some directions on how to solve this.

Comment: Try to avoid using `F` as an object name as R uses it `False`

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` on each `df2`s row, using `as.formula()` and `aes_string()`:

```
apply(df2, 1, function(d)
        {

        fit <- lm(as.formula(paste(d["Upstream"], " ~ ", d["Downstream"])), data=df1)

        lm_eqn <- function(df){
                m <- lm(as.formula(paste(d["Upstream"], " ~ ", d["Downstream"])), df);
                eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(R)^2~"="~r2* "," ~~ RMSE ~"="~rmse, 
                                 list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
                                      b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2),
                                      r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3),
                                      rmse = round(sqrt(mean(resid(m)^2,na.rm=TRUE)), 3)))
                as.character(as.expression(eq));
        }

        library(ggplot2)
        library(grid)
        library(gridExtra)

        p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes_string(x=d["Upstream"], y=d["Downstream"])) + geom_point(colour="red",size = 3) + geom_smooth(method=lm) + geom_text(aes(size=10),x = -Inf, hjust = -1, y = Inf, vjust = 1, label = lm_eqn(df1), parse = TRUE,show.legend = FALSE)
        p2 <-  ggplot(df1, aes_string(x=d["Downstream"], y=resid(fit))) + ylab("Residuals") + geom_point(shape=1,colour="red",size = 3) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
        grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2,top=textGrob("Regression data", 
                                                 gp=gpar(cex=1.5, fontface="bold")))
        })
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much HubertL. I have one more small question. How can we save these images one after the other into a pdf file? Could you please help me with that?

Comment: To save the plots in a pdf, call `pdf("plotList.pdf")` just before the apply, and `dev.off()` right after.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using `reshape2` to organize your data and `plyr` to run the regression and plots on the data subsets:

```
library(reshape2)

df3 <- cbind(
  #melt(data, id.vars, measure.vars, variable.name, value.name)
  melt(df1, c("ID"), df2$Upstream,   "up",   "Independent.var"),
  melt(df1, c("ID"), df2$Downstream, "down", "Dependent.var")
)
#df3    #Results of the above cbind(melt, melt)
#      ID up value    ID down Dependent.var
#1  ID101  A   420 ID101    B           230
#2  ID102  A   440 ID102    B           240
#3  ID103  A   490 ID103    B           295
#     .    .    .     .     .            .
#28 ID108  E    44 ID108    F           944
#29 ID109  E    68 ID109    F           918
#30 ID110  E    91 ID110    F           921


#Small edit to the labeling function:
lm_eqn <- function(df){
  m <- lm(Dependent.var ~ Independent.var, df);  #This is the only change
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(R)^2~"="~r2* "," ~~ RMSE ~"="~rmse, 
                   list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3),
                        rmse = round(sqrt(mean(resid(m)^2,na.rm=TRUE)), 3)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));
}

# Put your plot code into a function.
plotter <- function(zz) {
  zz$resid <- resid(lm(Dependent.var ~ Independent.var, zz))
  p1 <- ggplot(zz, aes(x= Independent.var, y= Dependent.var)) + 
    geom_point(colour="red",size = 3) + geom_smooth(method=lm) + 
    geom_text( aes(size=10),x = -Inf, hjust = -2, y = Inf, vjust = 1, label = lm_eqn(zz), parse = TRUE,show.legend = FALSE)
  p2 <-  ggplot(zz, aes(x= Dependent.var, y=resid )) + ylab("Residuals") + 
    geom_point(shape=1,colour="red",size = 3) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
  p3 <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2,top=textGrob("Regression data", 
                                               gp=gpar(cex=1.5, fontface="bold")))
  #Choose what you want to output here.  You can output a list: ex. list(fit, graph, etc)
  p3      #Only the last plot is returned in this case
}

library(plyr)

#Run on every subset of data:
#dlply = take input (d)ataframe and output a (l)ist using (ply)r
dlply(df3, .variables = c("up"), .fun = plotter)
  #p3 is output in list format
```